# How to use SQL Server 2016 to select JSON array where

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

```
{
    "NameDetailInfo": [{
        "cName": "Tony",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "cName": "Lucy",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "cName": "Lily",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "cName": "Ben",
        "sex": "M"
    }, {
        "cName": "Daa",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "cName": "Kode",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "cName": "Andy",
        "sex": "F"
    }, {
        "cName": "Koya",
         "sex": "F"
    },{
        "cName": "Kay",
        "sex": "M"
    }]
}
```

I want select this array `cName`.

```
select *
from CD_Name_List
where JSON_VALUE(CD_Name_List.MemberJSON,'$.NameDetailInfo[0].cName') = 'Kay'
```

This just select `NameDetailInfo[0]`, but I want select all array.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `OPENJSON` to break out the array

```sql
SELECT j.cName, j.sex
FROM CD_Name_List nl
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (nl.MemberJSON, '$.NameDetailInfo')
  WITH (cName nvarchar(100), sex char(1)) j
WHERE j.cName = 'Kay';
```

Or, if you meant that you want to select the whole array if such an element exists, you can use `OPENJSON` in a subquery

```
SELECT nl.*
FROM CD_Name_List nl
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON (nl.MemberJSON, '$.NameDetailInfo')
      WITH (cName nvarchar(100)) j
    WHERE j.cName = 'Kay'
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f2ed3af805d2f3710af25ab54762df3)